# Multiple editing of CSV files

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a small delay with operating CSV files in python (3.5). Previously I was working with single files and there was no problem, but right now I have >100 files in one folder.
So, my goal is:

1. To parse all *.csv files in the directory
2. From each file delete first 6 rows , the files consists of the following data:

   ```
   "nu(Ep), 2.6.8"
   "Date: 2/10/16, 11:18:21 AM"
   19
   Ep,nu
   0.0952645,0.123776,
   0.119036,0.157720,
   ...
   0.992060,0.374300,
   ```
3. Save each file separately (for example adding `"_edited"`), so there should be only numbers saved.
4. As an option - I have data subdivided on two parts for one material. For example: `Ag(0-1_s).csv` and `Ag(1-4)_s.csv` (after steps 1-3 the should be like `Ag(*)_edited.csv`). How can I merge this two files in a way of adding data from (1-4) to the end of (0-1) saving it in a third file?

My code so far is the following:

```
import os, sys
import csv
import re
import glob
import fileinput


def get_all_files(directory, extension='.csv'):
    dir_list = os.listdir(directory)
    csv_files = []
    for i in dir_list:
        if i.endswith(extension):
            csv_files.append(os.path.realpath(i))
    return csv_files

csv_files = get_all_files('/Directory/Path/Here')

#Here is the problem with csv's, I dont know how to scan files
#which are in the list "csv_files".

for n in csv_files:
    #print(n)
    lines = [] #empty, because I dont know how to write it properly per
               #each file
    input = open(n, 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(n)
    temp = []
    for i in range(5):
        next(reader)
        #a for loop for here regarding rows?
        #for row in n: ???
        #  ???
    input.close()
    #newfilename = "".join(n.split(".csv")) + "edited.csv"
    #newfilename can be used within open() below:
    with open(n + '_edited.csv', 'w') as nf:
        writer = csv.writer(nf)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fastest way I can think of. If you have a solid-state drive, you could throw multiprocessing at this for more of a performance boost

```
import glob
import os

for fpath in glob.glob('path/to/directory/*.csv'):
    fname = os.basename(fpath).rsplit(os.path.extsep, 1)[0]
    with open(fpath) as infile, open(os.path.join('path/to/dir', fname+"_edited"+os.path.extsep+'csv'), 'w') as outfile:
        for _ in range(6): infile.readline()
        for line in infile: outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I just changed 'fname = os.basename(fpath)' to 'fname = os.path.basename(fpath)'